# `stdout` is empty when passing data to `stdin` via `subprocess`, but contains the expected output when input is entered manually?

Tags: python, subprocess, chess, pexpect

So I'm working on trying to receive chess move data from the Leela Chess Zero engine. I am already done with all of the UI and other parts of the backend, and this is the last thing I need to implement. Unfortunately, I seem to have overestimated how simple subprocessing in Python is...

To explain a little more background, all I need to do is:

1. Call/run `lc0.exe` in the local directory. I have managed this just fine.
2. Pass the commands `position startpos e2e4 e7e5 e1e2`, `go nodes 100`, `quit` via stdin in that order. This also seems to work fine according to what I can gauge via stderr.
3. Receive/read stdout. This is where I'm stuck.

Here's the things I've tried so far:

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
>>> p = Popen(['lc0'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
>>> stdout_data = p.communicate(input=b'position startpos e2e4 e7e5 e1e2\ngo nodes 100\nquit')[0]
>>> stdout_data
b''
```

I get an empty byte string. I then tried a different method as a test:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(['lc0'], stderr=PIPE) #the following 3 lines is me typing into stdin
position startpos e2e4 e7e5 e1e2
go nodes 100
quit
b'info depth 1 seldepth 2 time 4081 nodes 4 score cp 12 nps 133 tbhits 0 pv e2e4 c7c5\r\ninfo depth 2 seldepth 3 time 4116 nodes 11 score cp 13 nps 166 tbhits 0 pv e2e4 c7c5 g1f3\r\ninfo depth 3 seldepth 4 time 4151 nodes 25 score cp 13 nps 247 tbhits 0 pv e2e4 c7c5 g1f3 e7e6\r\ninfo depth 3 seldepth 5 time 4218 nodes 68 score cp 13 nps 407 tbhits 0 pv e2e4 c7c5 b1c3 b8c6 g1e2\r\ninfo depth 4 seldepth 6 time 4312 nodes 134 score cp 13 nps 513 tbhits 0 pv e2e4 c7c5 b1c3 b8c6 g1f3 e7e5\r\nbestmove e2e4 ponder c7c5\r\n'
```

Eureka! I received the correct output from stdout. Now time to do it programatically:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(['lc0'], stderr=PIPE, input=b'position startpos e2e4 e7e5 e1e2\ngo nodes 100\nquit')
b''
```

Bugger! What is happening here? I can confirm by removing the `stderr=PIPE` argument that all of the commands apparently are indeed being run by the engine, but when all is said and done, stdout is empty when I pass the commands programatically. I've also tried using `subprocess.stdin.write()` with identical results.

After digging a lot, I found that `pexpect` might be more suitable for this use case. I installed `pip install wexpect` and lo' and behold:

```
>>> from wexpect import spawn
>>> child = spawn("lc0")

...
```

Yup, it just hangs. Breaking with ^C gives me the exception `pywintypes.error: (2, 'CreateFile', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')`, so I understandably feel less confident about using `pexpect` instead of `subprocess`, since I seem much closer to a solution with the latter.

Anyways, I'm convinced I'm misuing `subprocess` somehow, but what exactly am I doing wrong? Why am I correctly receiving `stdout` when passing commands through `stdin` manually, but not when using the `input=` argument?

Comment: Try adding the final missing `\n` in the input string.

Comment: @meuh unfortunately doesn't make a difference. Curiously the presence or lack of the `quit` command doesn't seem to have any effect on the output from `subprocess`. stderr still gets filled up with the same information as if the position and go commands get executed, so I'm honestly pretty confused what's happening under the hood now.

Comment: Perhaps if you are using windows you need `\r\n` or just `\r` instead of `\n` as line endings for the input?

Comment: Already tried that as well; same result. I'm pretty sure most CLI apps specifically look for the `\n` character alone when evaluating whether enter was pressed anyways.

Comment: If you want to you can single-step through the python code. There are several debuggers, including a gui `idle` which I don't know, but there is a builtin simple `pdb`. It shouldn't be too bad if you only use it after the `Popen()` call. In the interpreter type `import pydb; pdb.runeval("subprocess.check_output(...)")` then at the `(Pdb)` prompt type `s` to step, `n` for next to not trace this line, `h` for help, return to repeat the last command. But it will probably only confirm that there is no output! Try subprocess on another, simpler, command first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use stdin.write() to send command to the engine one at a time. Also properly send the position command with `moves` as in:
`position startpos moves m1, m2 ...` Safely quit the engine and properly terminate the process.

##### Code

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT, TimeoutExpired


def ecommand(p, comm):
    p.stdin.write(f'{comm}\n')


def analyze(efile):
    bestmove = '0000'

    p = Popen([efile], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=0, text=True)  # stderr=STDOUT, also send stderr to stdout to see everything in stdout

    ecommand(p, 'position startpos moves e2e4 e7e5 e1e2')
    ecommand(p, 'go nodes 3000')

    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):  # read each line of engine output as replies from our command
        line = line.strip()
        print(line)

        if line.startswith('bestmove'):  # exit the loop when we get the engine bestmove
            bestmove = line.split()[1].strip()
            break

    ecommand(p, 'quit')  # properly quit the engine

    # Make sure process 'p' is terminated (if not terminated for some reason) as we already sent the quit command.
    try:
        p.communicate(timeout=5)
    except TimeoutExpired:  # If timeout has expired and process is still not terminated.
        p.kill()
        p.communicate()

    return bestmove


efile = 'E:\\Chess_Engines\\Lc0\\lc0-v0.28.0-windows-cpu-openblas\\lc0.exe'
bestmove = analyze(efile)
print(f'best move: {bestmove}')
```

##### Output

```
_
|   _ | |
|_ |_ |_| v0.28.0 built Aug 25 2021
Detected 4 core(s) and 8 thread(s) in 1 group(s).
...

info depth 1 seldepth 2 time 181 nodes 2 score cp 88 nps 142 tbhits 0 pv g8f6 d2d3
info depth 2 seldepth 3 time 200 nodes 3 score cp 89 nps 90 tbhits 0 pv g8f6 d2d3 d7d5
info depth 2 seldepth 4 time 236 nodes 5 score cp 93 nps 72 tbhits 0 pv g8f6 b1c3 b8c6 d2d3
info depth 3 seldepth 5 time 305 nodes 15 score cp 99 nps 107 tbhits 0 pv g8f6 d2d3 d7d5 b1c3 d5d4
info depth 3 seldepth 6 time 368 nodes 23 score cp 96 nps 114 tbhits 0 pv g8f6 d2d3 d7d5 b1c3 d5d4 c3b1
info depth 4 seldepth 7 time 466 nodes 34 score cp 105 nps 113 tbhits 0 pv g8f6 d2d3 d7d5 b1c3 d5d4 c3b1 b8c6
info depth 4 seldepth 8 time 561 nodes 55 score cp 106 nps 139 tbhits 0 pv g8f6 d2d3 d7d5 b1c3 d5d4 c3b1 b8c6
info depth 5 seldepth 8 time 871 nodes 105 score cp 109 nps 149 tbhits 0 pv g8f6 d2d3 d7d5 b1c3 b8c6 c1g5 c8e6 g1f3
info depth 5 seldepth 9 time 965 nodes 119 score cp 111 nps 149 tbhits 0 pv g8f6 d2d3 d7d5 b1c3 b8c6 c1g5 c8e6 g1f3
info depth 5 seldepth 10 time 1327 nodes 179 score cp 109 nps 154 tbhits 0 pv g8f6 d2d3 d7d5 b1c3 b8c6 c1g5 c8e6 g1f3 d5d4
info depth 5 seldepth 11 time 1444 nodes 206 score cp 110 nps 161 tbhits 0 pv g8f6 d2d3 d7d5 b1c3 b8c6 c1g5 c8e6 g1f3 d5d4 c3b1
info depth 5 seldepth 12 time 1621 nodes 240 score cp 110 nps 165 tbhits 0 pv g8f6 d2d3 d7d5 b1c3 b8c6 c1g5 c8e6 g1f3 d5d4 c3b1
info depth 6 seldepth 12 time 2126 nodes 331 score cp 112 nps 168 tbhits 0 pv g8f6 d2d3 d7d5 b1c3 b8c6 c1g5 c8e6 g1f3 d5d4 c3b1
info depth 6 seldepth 13 time 2582 nodes 430 score cp 111 nps 178 tbhits 0 pv g8f6 d2d3 d7d5 b1c3 b8c6 c1g5 c8e6 g1f3 d5d4 c3b1
info depth 6 seldepth 14 time 5050 nodes 1037 score cp 111 nps 212 tbhits 0 pv g8f6 d2d3 d7d5 b1c3 b8c6 c1g5 c8e6 e4d5 c6d4 e2d2 e6d5
info depth 7 seldepth 14 time 5569 nodes 1161 score cp 111 nps 214 tbhits 0 pv g8f6 d2d3 d7d5 b1c3 b8c6 c1g5 c8e6 e4d5 c6d4 e2d2 e6d5
info depth 7 seldepth 15 time 8385 nodes 1938 score cp 109 nps 235 tbhits 0 pv g8f6 d2d3 d7d5 b1c3 b8c6 c1g5 c6d4 e2e1 c7c6 g1f3 d8b6 a1b1 c8e6 f3e5
info depth 7 seldepth 15 time 8642 nodes 2007 score cp 109 nps 236 tbhits 0 pv g8f6 d2d3 d7d5 b1c3 b8c6 c1g5 c6d4 e2e1 c7c6 g1f3 d8b6 a1b1 c8e6 f3e5
bestmove g8f6 ponder d2d3
best move: g8f6
```

Comment: WOW! Nearly half a year after I put this project on hiatus due to this issue, you come along and fix it for me! I don't have time to test your solution just yet, but I will mark it (hopefully not in vain) as solved! Thank you!